# you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, crystal-reports

'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer' does not contain a definition for 'ReportSource' and no extension method 'ReportSource' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinFord (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Please help

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

"are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference" means that you have lost some assemblies . you need to add.